# Bash (on mac) - how to a folder structure over with some conditions

Tags: macos, bash

I have a folder structure A

```
A
|-Directory X1
|--File 1
|--File 2
|--File 3
|-Directory X2
|--File 1
|--File 2
```

I also have folder structure B

```
B
|-Directory X1
|--File 1
|--File 2
|--File 3
|-Directory X2
|--File 1
|--File 2
|--File 3        <--- This files doesn't exist in folder structure A
|-Directory X3   <--- This folder doesn't exist in folder structure A
|--File 1
|--File 2
|--File 3
```

MY goal is a command line that'll copy structure B over to structure A, replace all its files, copy all the files missing in A, create the folders that A doesn't have but B does and copy over the files in those folders.

The end result should be folder A with:

```
A
|-Directory X1
|--File 1
|--File 2
|--File 3
|-Directory X2
|--File 1
|--File 2
|--File 3
|-Directory X3
|--File 1
|--File 2
|--File 3
```

Comment: `cp -an` (archive + noclobber)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` will do this.

```
rsync -avz B/* A
```

Look into the `--delete*` arguments if you want files that exist in `A/` but not `B/` removed.